# Magento/Zend_Db Order By Expression

Tags: mysql, query, zend-framework

Take this code for example:

```
$collection->getSelect()->order(array('status = 1 DESC', 'test ASC'));
```

Magento/Zend_Db turns this into the following:

```
ORDER BY `status = 1` DESC, `test` ASC
```

You can see this with `Zend_Debug::dump($collection->getSelect()->__toString());`

Notice that it wraps `status = 1` with ` characters, as if it were escaping a field? This breaks the query. Is there any way to order by expression in Magento/Zend_Db?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would think `new Zend_Db_Expr` would do what you need.

`$collection->getSelect()->order(array(new Zend_Db_Expr('status = 1 DESC'), 'test ASC'))`

Details:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9957584/magento-collection-expression